# Type Mismatch - Required: Fragment when trying to replace a fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

I am trying to replace a fragment with another but I am encountering the compile-time error:

```
Type Mismatch
Required:  Fragment! 
Found:   GalleryFragment
```

This is the code that's causing the error:

```
val fragment = GalleryFragment()
val arguments = Bundle()
arguments.putInt("NumeroQuestion", enfantActuel)

fragment.arguments = arguments
activity.fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,fragment)?.commit() //here
```

I am not sure what I am supposed to put instead of `fragment`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `GalleryFragment` inherits from `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` then you need to be using the support fragment manager:

```
activity.supportFragmentManager
```

---

[`Activity.getFragmentManager()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#getFragmentManager()) has been deprecated since since API 28.